# Join Parent, Child and GrandChild tables with latest record from grandchild table using LinQ in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

**Please note this is just to simulate the example but not the actual tables itself.**

*Apologies for long question*

I have three tables Vendor, Product and Orders. They are linked like below.

Vendor --> Id, Name, Location (this table has all info regarding vendor)

Product --> Id, VendorId, Name, Description (this table has all the product that vendor sells)

Orders --> Id,ProductId,Date (this table has all the Orders placed for that product)

Vendor has One to One relationship with Product table but some of the vendors may not have product at all.

Product table has one to many relationship with Orders table

I am trying to get the latest Order placed for a Vendor using linq.

Example.

Vendor :

```
     1 | Microsoft | Seattle
     2 | Apple     | California
     3 | Amazon    | Seattle
```

Product :

```
     1 | 1 | MS Office | Office Suite
     2 | 2 | iPhone    | Smart Phone
```

Order:

```
     1 | 1 | 05/27/2016
     2 | 1 | 06/07/2016
     3 | 2 | 04/17/2016
     4 | 2 | 06/01/2016
```

Expected Result:

```
     1 | Microsoft | Seattle
          1 | 1 | MS Office | Office Suite
                2 | 1 | 06/07/2016

     2 | Apple | California
          2 | 2 | iPhone | Smart Phone
                4 | 2 | 06/01/2016

     3 | Amazon | Seattle
          null
              null


var vendor = db.Vendor.Include(x => x.Product.Select(s => s.Order)).OrderBy(a => a.Name).Select(s => new VendorModel
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            Location = c.Location

            Product = c.Product.Select(m => new ProductModel
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                VendorId = m.VendorId,
                Name = m.Name,
                Description = m.Description,
            }).FirstOrDefault(),

            Order = c.Order.Select(m => new OrderModel
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                ProductId = m.ProductId,
                Date = m.Date,
            }).OrderBy(o=>o.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        });

public class VendorModel
{
    public ApplicationModel() { }
    public ApplicationModel(int id, string name, string location)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Location = location;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location{ get; set; }
    public virtual ProductModel Product { get; set; }
    public virtual OrderModel Order { get; set; }
}

 public class ProductModel 
{
    public ProductModel() { }
    public ProductModel(int id, int vendorId, string name, string description)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.VendorId = vendorId;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public VendorModel Vendor { get; set; } 
}


public class OrderModel
{
    public OrderModel() { }
    public OrderModel(int id, int productId, DateTime date)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ProductId = productId;
        this.Date = date;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ProductModel Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "*Vendor has One to One relationship with Product table*" Are you sure it's not `one to many`. From `x.Product.Select(...` looks like `x.Product` is a collection? Or the sample is incorrect. It would be nice if you provide sample entity classes rather than describing the tables and fields.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to review the question. I updated the post with entity model. Please review and make suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome. However the model doesn't seem to represent correctly the tables you have described. I would expect `Vendor` to have `ICollection<Product> Products` property, and `Product` to have `ICollection<Orders> Orders`. See, the query shouldn't be an issue as soon as we have a correct model with correct navigation properties, because EF generates the necessary joins based on that information, and inside the query we need to just "navigate" from parent to child to grandchild and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

As Vendor might have null value, I think you should use Left outer joins. Here is how you could implement left outer joins with LINQ.

```
var query = from v in Vendor
            join p in Product on v.id equals p.vendorId into t1
            from vp in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join o in Orders on p.id equals o.productId t2
            from vpo in t2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby v.Name, vpo.date 

select new
{
    v.Name, v.Location,
    productId=(int?)vp.id,  // To handle null value if id(ProductId) is specified as not null in Product table.
    vp.Name, vp.Description,
    orderId = (int?)vpo.id, // To handle null value if id(OrderId) is specified as not null in Orders table.
    vpo.date 
}.ToList();
```